# How to access nested properties in MYSQL JSON column

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a json column named 'request' that contains this value:

```json
{
  "id": "2890",
  "temperature": "22.25",
  "entries": "[{\"user_id\":\"31823\",\"auth_type\":\"RFID\"}]"
}
```

When I run the following mysql query I get `null`, but I would expect to get `"RFID"`.  How can get to the value of "auth_type". I've run multiple variations of this query, but I feel like this one should work.

```sql
select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(request, '$.entries[0].auth_type')) as entries FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(request, '$.entries') is not null LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Your attempt should just work. And it can be also expressed more neatly like so: `request ->> '$.entries[0].auth_type'`. https://dbfiddle.uk/d7kZQq8D

Comment: I thought it should have worked as well.  I even tried with `->>` and other variations, but it would not parse the entries key without the double `JSON_EXTRACT`.

Answer (score 0):

After spending an hour trying to figure it out I found the answer 60 seconds after posting my question.  This query gets the job done:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(request, '$.entries')), '$[0].auth_type') as entries 
FROM mytable
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(request, '$.entries') is not null 
LIMIT 1;
```

But, the double `JSON_EXTRACT` seems strange.  If the data was further nested I would need to continue wrapping extract statements to drill down.  So, I found an answer the works, I'm just not sure it is the best answer.

--update

The reason for the double extract has to do with the format of the data in the database. The original format can be seen in the initial post.  It has quotes around the array "[]" which is not valid JSON. To be valid, it should look like this:

```json
{
  "id": "2890",
  "temperature": "22.25",
  "entries": [{\"user_id\":\"31823\",\"auth_type\":\"RFID\"}]
}
```

Without the quotes `request->> '$.entries[0].auth_type'` works as expected.